# Clean spaces in an extracted list of authors packages in R

Tags: r

I face a "strange" issue with a code that I have written in R to extract all the authors of the R packages installed on my computer. Indeed, I try to remove undesirable spaces before and after the commas ( , ) but I can't get the expected clean result using R text cleaning common techniques.

Here is the script for reproduction so that you can see the issue in the final result on your own screen:

```
library("tools")
pdb<-CRAN_package_db()
subset<-pdb[,c(1,17)]
ipck<-as.vector(installed.packages()[,1])
pdbCleaned <- subset[subset$Package %in% ipck, ]
pdbCleaned$Author

Authors <-gsub("[\r\n]", "", pdbCleaned$Author)
Authors <-gsub("\\[.*?\\]", "", Authors)
Authors <-gsub("\\(.*?\\)", "", Authors)
Authors <-gsub("<.*>", "", Authors)
Authors <-gsub("))", "", Authors)
Authors <-gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", " ", Authors)
Authors
```

Comment: In general, it's good to tell us explicitly what the error is, and what your desired result is. Here I think you are having some problems with your final regex? Is your desired result a vector of comma-separated author names, with each package having one index, with no other info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt at a solution with `stringr`. Note that you don't have to match your installed packages to the entire CRAN db, you can just pull the author field from your installed packages.

I just use two regexes: one to remove anything wrapped in `[]`, `()`, `<>` which is often things like `[aut]` or `<email@domain>`, and one to remove anything with spaces surrounding `,` or `and`. Note that depending on the packages you have installed this will work varyingly well. You will have to tweak to adjust for the packages you have, for example I might want to remove double commas `,,` because of the `ada` package. Other packages just have a lot of random text in their `Author` field which makes it hard to manage automatically, such as the `akima` package. But as a first pass this should do the trick.

```r
library(tidyverse)
authors <- installed.packages(fields = "Author") %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  select(package = Package, author = Author)

authors %>%
  mutate(
    author = str_replace_all(author, "(\\[|\\(|<).*(\\]|\\)|>)", ""),
    author = str_replace_all(author, "[:space:]*(,|and)[:space:]*", ","),
    author = str_trim(author)
  )
#> # A tibble: 620 x 2
#>    package   author                                                       
#>    <chr>     <chr>                                                        
#>  1 abind     Tony Plate,Richard Heiberger                                 
#>  2 actuar    Vincent Goulet,Sébastien Auclair,Christophe Dutang,Xavier Mi~
#>  3 ada       Mark Culp,Kjell Johnson,,George Michailidis                  
#>  4 AER       Christian Kleiber,Achim Zeileis                              
#>  5 AGD       Stef van Buuren                                              
#>  6 agricolae Felipe de Mendiburu                                          
#>  7 akima     "Hiroshi Akima,Albrecht Gebhardt,bicubic*\n    functions),Th~
#>  8 alr3      Sanford Weisberg                                             
#>  9 alr4      Sanford Weisberg                                             
#> 10 amap      Antoine Lucas                                                
#> # ... with 610 more rows
```

Created on 2018-03-14 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).